# Создание асинхронных задач

Tags: php, yii2, асинхронность

Ни разу не работал с асинхронностью в PHP. По большей части оно и не надо, но у меня такая задача: юзер жмет кнопочку, делается запрос который вроде как запускает задачу по конвертации некоторых файлов. Но конвертация - дело довольно длительное, а запрос должен быстро вернуться. Поэтому я хочу чтобы этот запрос как-бы запустил какую-то асинхронную задачу и тут же возвращался не дожидаясь выполнения. По выполнении даже ничего делать не нужно - запишет статус в базу что все сконвертировано и ок. Подскажите как такое сделать? Какую-то библиотеку нужно использовать?

Comment: Может быть поможет использование труб очередей?

Comment: @fedornabilkin что это? О_о Первый раз слышу

Comment: После нажатия на кнопку, создайте джобу и положите её в очередь задач, а крон, например, выполяент все джобы из очереди. Каждый элемент нужно будет реализовать вам.

Comment: Для yii2 вот есть расширение. Используем на проекте. https://github.com/udokmeci/yii2-beanstalk

Comment: @fedornabilkin Хмм, интересно, но сложновато для понимания... А что если использовать обычные [потоки, которые вроде бы тоже есть](http://php.net/manual/ru/class.thread.php) в пыхе?

Comment: Хотя нет. Эти потоки не канают. Кажется там должен быть подключен какой-то модуль pthreads которого у меня нет ни локально ни на сервере...

Comment: @fedornabilkin так это получается ему еще и какой-нибудь супервизор нужен? Чтобы его все время запущенным держать.

Comment: В общем мне кажется идея с кроном самая простая пока что. Т.е. я делаю консольный контроллер, когда появляется задача я пихаю ее данные в кэш (он у меня в редисе хранится) и методе консольного контроллера проверяю - не появилось ли новых задач и выполняю их. По крону запускаю этот контроллер каждые 10 секунд например. Интересно а если предыдущая задача еще не успеет завершиться что будет? Крон запускает задачи в отдельных потоках?

Comment: Крон - это обычный демон, можно сразу демона написать, курлом(без таймаута) его вызывать и он будет работать. Есть куча либ уже по асинхронному пхп

Comment: Все уже реализовано за вас. https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-queue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте официальное расширение [yii2-queue](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-queue)

Как применять смотрите в документации:
https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-queue/blob/master/docs/guide-ru/usage.md

Answer (score 0):

Если в процессе ничего не нужно возвращать (progress bar, например), а также в результате будет только "готово", то можете реализовать обычным Ajax запросом.

**Сценарий:**

1. Отправляется Ajax запрос с нужным файлом на сервер
2. На сайте вместо кнопки Submit появляется загрузчик (иконка), типа: Loading...
3. По завершению выполнения PHP отправляет ответ обратно клиенту. Тогда же убирается Loader и отображается Complete!

PS: Если пользователю дозволено листать сайт на момент "процесса", то можно также работать с Cookie + JS timeout (ну или node.js).